# Traefik with multiple subdomains and URLs with a subpath

Tags: docker, traefik

Setup: Docker (18.09.6) with one Traefik container, Apache container, multiple other containers (e.g. portainer running behind a subpath)
Apache is configured with

```
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${hostname},www.${hostname}
```

portainer is configured with

```
- traefik.frontend.redirect.regex=^(.*)/portainer$$
- traefik.frontend.redirect.replacement=$$1/portainer/
- "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/portainer;ReplacePathRegex: ^/portainer/(.*) /$$1"
```

Apache container is serving URLs https://hostname and e.g. https://hostname/test
Portainer container served via https://hostname/portainer

### Setup works!

Now I want to extend the subdomains for the Apache container like

```
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${hostname},autoconfig.${hostname},autodiscover.${hostname},mta-sts.${hostname},www.${hostname}
```

Now the following happens:
https://hostname works
https://hostname/test works
https://autodiscover.hostname works

**https://hostname/portainer stops working**
According to the logs Traefik routes the traffic to the Apache container instead of the Portainer container

This is reproduce able and related to multiple frontend entries. I didn't find an example with more than 2 frontend rules
also tried

```
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${hostname},Host:www.${hostname},Host:autoconfig.${hostname}
```

or

```
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${hostname};Host:www.${hostname};Host:autoconfig.${hostname}
```

it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Ta answer my own question (thx to dtomcej, ref URL https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4904)

```
The issue you are encountering is that you have overlapping rules, and you are not defining any priority to determine order of rule execution.

From the documentation (https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#priorities):

By default, routes will be sorted (in descending order) using rules length 

So since you have made the host rule much longer, and it matches, it is the first rule.

You can use the priority label to manually force the match of the portainer path first, before the base host match.
```

added traefik.frontend.priority=1 to my Apache container and traefik.frontend.priority=2 to all other container containing a subpath.